# Stream operations not in correct order

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Can someone please help me restructure the following observable stream so if an exception occurs during the getPreferences on the local provider the remote provider getPreferences will still occur?

thanks!

```
    @Effect() load$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType<Load>(LOAD)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
            return this._localProvider.getPreferences()
                .pipe(
                    tap((preferences: Preferences) => {
                        this._store.dispatch(new LoadSuccess(preferences));
                    }),
                    switchMap((preferences: Preferences) => {
                        return this._remoteProvider.getPreferences()
                            .pipe(
                                filter((remotePref: Preferences) => {
                                    return remotePref.timestamp$ > preferences.timestamp$;
                                }),
                                map((remotePref: Preferences) => {
                                    return new LoadSuccess(remotePref);
                                }),
                                catchError(error => {
                                    return of(new LoadError(error));
                                })
                            )
                    }),
                    catchError(error => {
                        return of(new LoadError(error));
                    })
                )
        }),
    );
```

Comment: How would that work ? You are using timestamp property from the local preferences.

Comment: And irrelevant of that you should separate this into two different effects. The first one that loads the local preferences and emits a load success / fail action and a different one that listens to that event and loads the remote ones.

Comment: i wanted these to load in parallel so splitting them out would not work well. i figured it out however.